Will the pilot bear any responsibility or be investigated if a passenger dies due to a medical emergency that the captain refused to act upon?
In the case of medical emergencies among the passengers, the pilot generally have the final say on whether or not the plane will be diverted. While this is true, I'm wondering what kind of responsibilities/liabilities will the pilot(s) face if they refuse to divert and the passenger died as a result? Will they be investigated and scrutinized by the FAA, their airliner, law enforcement, or any other governmental bodies? Or are they exempt from such responsibilities since it's their job to decide? Let's say the deceased passenger died of a normal condition, for example cardiac arrest or heart attack.
According to this post, deaths inflight are not extremely uncommon. An answer to this question also states the events following a passenger death on an aircraft.
However, they say nothing about the (potential) investigation and scrutiny of pilots if they refuse to divert for an ill passenger. Will there be any such investigations?

Could you give any indication as to why the captain might make the decision not to divert due to a medical situation on a plane? I downvoted due to the extremely speculative nature of this question, I cannot for the life of me come up with a scenarion where the pilot would refuse to divert without a solid, safety related reason in a case with an ill passenger.

@Jpe61 The point of my question is with an out-of-the-ordinary pilot. Normal pilot's won't do that, but you can't say no pilot would. The most "normal" (i.e, not unethical, just mistaken) reason would be that the passenger is originally not in a life-threatening situation, the aircraft was already delayed, and so the pilot decided to continue. But after over halfway into the flight, the situation worsens and became life-threatening. Before landing, the passenger's dead.

Ask law SE. I assume family would sue airline (where the money is), but you ask "responsibility" which seems more on criminal side, so complex: most rules "will not apply" (they do not have criminal delegation. Ask Law SE -- Also it depends on jurisdiction: countries have different view on priorities and procedures.

Definitely a law question more than an aviation question. This is probably going to be a discussion of negligence and duty of care, but honestly, I'm not sure there's a case on point. Without a specific case that addresses a very similar scenario, there may not be a solid answer -- just the arguments for and against that the lawyers would make.

"...the pilot generally have the final say on whether or not the plane will be diverted." The Pilot In Comman has the final say. Always, no exceptions.

Most aspects would be better answered at law.se, here is some food for thought only, and I hope better answers will be posted. I'm neither a pilot nor a legal advisor.
Your question "Will the pilot bear any responsibility or be investigated if a passenger dies due to a medical emergency that the captain refused to act upon?" is not meaningless, of course the decision to not divert may be mistakenly taken by a well-intentioned pilot, due to the different elements to be assessed.
However such situation is unlikely: The pilot (in command) won't be alone for deciding. They will be discussing with the ground flight dispatcher, assisted by a doctor, possibly a lawyer, and other experts. The dispatcher and the pilot-in-command will agree on the final decision. This restrict the risk of a wrong decision. Even if a diversion is a costly operation for the operator, they won't take the risk of having their image degraded in the long term for "not willing to spend a few dollars and save a life".
It's the opposite, they may want to divert even if there is no real benefit for the person requiring medical attention, because article 17.1 of the Warsaw convention presuppose damage liability of the operator for any in-flight injury or death of a passenger, regardless of the reason, thought only up to a certain amount.
If a wrong decision is taken, then the operator employees, including the pilot-in-command and the dispatcher, and their management may be prosecuted, and sentenced if faults are proven. These employees have no specific privileges or protection.

There are different aspects to consider:

When you write "pilot" (as pilot flying), you should use "pilot in command" (PIC). For commercial carriers, the PIC, who has the rank of Captain in some countries, Commander in other, represents the operator authority for important decisions like a diversion.

When you write "responsible" you should use "liable" as except specific cases, everybody is accountable of their actions. Legal liability can be of two kinds: For the action and/or for the consequences of the action:

Sanction for the author of an action breaching a legal obligation (penal/criminal action by the State).
Victim compensation for the consequences of a fault, regardless of whether the law has been breached (civil/litigation action by the victim).



The base for liability and compensation is Warsaw Convention. Liability is not limited to the crew, the crew as been trained by an employer and receives instructions from a manager.

When risk is considered by the PIC, it is not limited to risk for the passenger in medical emergency, but is extended to the risk associated with the diversion:

Maybe the only possible diversion airfield has no medical structure and, this may reduce the passenger chances to be medically assisted.

Maybe the landing will be difficult due to weather conditions and the life of all passengers might be at stake.



In a commercial air transport environment, the crew doesn't act alone, they have a counterpart on the ground, the flight dispatcher  or Operations, who can provide advice and instructions.
For more see What is the role of the flight dispatcher? How do the dispatcher and the flight crew interact?.
The liability will now be shared. Operations will ask for a medical advice and decide what to do, possibly assisted by the operator's lawyer.

The crew will also ask for medical expertise on-board. A doctor on-board has likely no (legal) obligation to offer or accept to provide assistance, and if they do the legal liability is not very clear. These two elements may depend on the State of registration of the aircraft and/or the nationality of the doctor. The in-board doctor may or may not suggest an immediate landing. This is taken into account too when determining iability.

A diversion is a huge cost for the operator, this cost won't be covered by the passenger insurance. So the decision is not limited to well-being considerations. On the other hand not diverting, even for valid reasons, may have a huge commercial impact.


An operator has an overall obligation to take care of the passengers and their safety. It is liable for any damage. But there is apparently no law like "the flight termination is required in case of death-threatening situation".
In addition, there are no international laws, so an answer to your question maybe State-dependent, or even may depend on which territory or water area is currently overflown:

So-called international obligations are the results of bilateral or multilateral treaties like Chicago Convention, and, for liability, Warsaw Convention and Montreal Convention. These treaties are obligations for the States, and are implemented by signatories into their own law in order to be applicable to their citizens. This implementation can lead to local variations.

In some countries everyone can be sanctioned for not providing assistance to someone whose life is threatened, e.g. Non-assistance à personne en danger in French law. This individual obligation has a precedence higher than most other collective or professional obligations.


In the context of air transport, the latter obligation of assistance specifically means:

A French doctor in an aircraft registered in France must offer help in case of medical emergency (this is not limited to doctors, other professions are concerned).

The PIC can be taken to a court for a breach of this single obligation, no need for the existence of a professional fault. However again, it must be proved the PIC had the elements to evaluate the situation and the decision to not land wasn't motivated by valid reasons.


All in all, diverting is a PIC's decision based on their own judgment, taking into account all elements. As for any decision, the PIC will be liable and must demonstrate this decision was a good one. Think of the emergency ditching in the Hudson: Is it a good decision? should I try to land at the closest airfield to prevent drownings? After the facts the PIC had to explain and prove this was a sensible decision. The fact this decision was sensible had likely a huge financial impact for paying the enormous associated costs and damages.

Thanks to @Jpe61 for mentioning the difference PIC/Captain.
